# TFS allowing me to access just one class out of five classes in the same folder in .net

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm very new to working with TFS(of course not with Visual Studio). I have 6 projects in same solution and one of the projects has a folder with 6 c-sharp classes in it. When i try to access these classes from inside of other projects ( which all are in the same solution) except one class other five classes don't appear in the intellisense.
I have manually added reference to this project in other project. Which is why I'm able to access one class but my confusion is why not other classes are accessible through intellisense.

Did I do something wrong. I did check-in whatever pending changes were there in the entire solution still no luck.

Your help will be highly appreciated

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;
       using NS.GIS.PTC.Core.Entities;


namespace NS.GIS.PTC.WebServices.DataManagement.Model.Dtos
{
    public class FieldDescriptionDto
    {

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Alias
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Length
        {
            get;
            set;

        }

        public bool IsSystem
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Domain Domain
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
}
```

here is the code and below is the code that is using it I have written it forcibly coz as u know its not appearing in intellisense

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NS.GIS.PTC.Core.Entities;
using NS.GIS.PTC.WebService.DataManagement.Model.Dtos;

namespace NS.GIS.PTC.WebService.DataManagement.API.Model
{
    internal static class FieldDescriptionExtension
    {
        internal static FieldDescriptionDto ToFieldDescriptionDto(this FieldDescription       fieldDescription)
        {
            return new FieldDescriptionDto
            {
                Name = fieldDescription.Name,
                Type = fieldDescription.Type,
                Alias= fieldDescription.Alias,
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if all the classes are marked Public.
2. Check if their namespaces have been included.
3. Restart VS and try.
4. Forcibly use them and see if you get a squiggle to auto-include namespace etc.

Comment: Tried all your suggestions still no luck.

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet and the error when you build it or try to use the class?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'FieldDescriptionDto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)This is the error that I get when I compile my program.

Comment: But if using directive or an assembly is missing then why one of the class from same folder is appearing in intellisense and working fine why not other classes in the same folder

Comment: Can you paste definition of this class? Just namespace and class declaration. And also the usage code. Along with the class usage that works. Basically provide maximum code that you can.

Comment: Yes it is strange. Code helps us identify the root cause.

Comment: Another weird thing is that within the same all the classes are accessible and appearing inside of each other but the class that is accessible in other projects is not appearing inside of classes in the same folder...I have no idea what's going on in here. That's why I never liked TFS.It's way way easy to solve all this in visual studio local instance rather than TFS

Comment: In the calling assembly can you add a reference to the core.entities assembly as well and try again

Comment: I got it someone on TFS has created 2 namespaces Webservices and Webservice and for some reason(which I couldn't figure out) adding classes in to same folder are getting reflected in Webservices namespace rather than Webservice, which is the namespace that I'm working with. Thanks for your help raja.